# ¿Por qué no funciona mi aplicacion con firebase database android? (login)

Tags: android

Tengo esta aplicación, que básicamente es un login. También tengo una base de datos en Firebase. Todos las referencias a la base de datos están bien escritas, pero mi app ni siquiera entra en los Listeners de las bases de datos, he probado con los logs y tampoco me da ningún error. Aquí está el código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText miEditTextLoginNombre, miEditTextLoginPass;
    private Button miBotonLoginEntrar;
    private DatabaseReference alumnos;
    private DatabaseReference profesores;
    private DatabaseReference admins;
    private Admin admin = null;
    private Alumno alum = null;
    private Profesor profe = null;
    private String usuario, contra;
    boolean isAdmin = false;
    boolean isUser = false;
    Snackbar sBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        miEditTextLoginNombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLoginNombre);
        miEditTextLoginPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLoginPass);
        miBotonLoginEntrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoginEntrar);

        alumnos = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(FirebaseReferences.ALUMNOS_REF);
        profesores = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(FirebaseReferences.PROFESORES_REF);
        admins = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(FirebaseReferences.ADMINS_REF);

        miBotonLoginEntrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                usuario = miEditTextLoginNombre.getText().toString();
                contra = miEditTextLoginPass.getText().toString();

                if(usuario.isEmpty() || contra.isEmpty()){
                    sBar = Snackbar.make(view, "Hay campos vacíos", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    sBar.show();
                }else{
                    comprobarUsuario();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void comprobarUsuario(){
        alumnos.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){                        
                    if(snap.child("dni_alum").equals(usuario) && snap.child("clave").equals(contra)){

                        alum = dataSnapshot.getValue(Alumno.class);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        profesores.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if(snap.child("dni_profe").equals(usuario) && snap.child("clave").equals(contra)){
                        profe = dataSnapshot.getValue(Profesor.class);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        admins.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if(snap.child("dni").getValue().equals(usuario) && snap.child("clave").getValue().equals(contra)){
                        admin = snap.getValue(Admin.class);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        if(admin != null){
            isAdmin = true;
        }

        if(profe != null || alum != null){
            isUser = true;
        }

        if(isUser == false && isAdmin == false){
            FragmentManager fragment = getSupportFragmentManager();
            DialogoAlerta a = new DialogoAlerta();
            a.show(fragment, "alerta");
        }else if(isUser == false && isAdmin == true){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Has iniciado sesión como Admin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(isUser == true && isAdmin == false){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Has iniciado sesión como User", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Mi base de datos está construida de la siguiente forma:
 - proyecto:
 - ALUMNOS
    - dni
    - clave
 - PROFESORES
    - dni
    - clave
 - ADMINS
    - dni
    - clave

Answer (score 2):

es sencillo, hay algunos errores que estás comentiendo con Firebase, yo mi recomendación es que lo hagas así, he trabajado mucho con firebase y para mi ha sido la mejor manera (Esta codificado en Sublime, puede haber algún error de sintaxis)
Recuerda también en Firebase poner los datos de escritura y lectura sin necesidad de login. Tambien te recomiendo usar el login que trae firebase de casa, es mucho mas seguro.

1. Creas una interfaz para validar los datos:
   MAININTERFACE.class

   ```
   public interface MainInterface {
   interface View{
       <T> void onSuccess(T t);
       void onError(String error);
   }
   interface Model{
       void handleCheck(String username, String password);
   }
   ```

   }

Te creas un Modelo para gestionar Firebase implementando el Model de la interfaz:

```
public class MainModel implements MainInterface.Model{

private MainInterface.View view;
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference alumnos;
private DatabaseReference profesores;
private DatabaseReference admins;

public MainModel(MainInterface.View view) {
    this.view = view;
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    alumnos = database.getReference(FirebaseReferences.ALUMNOS_REF);
    profesores = database.getReference(FirebaseReferences.PROFESORES_REF);
    admins = database.getReference(FirebaseReferences.ADMINS_REF);
}

@Override
public void handleCheck(String username, String password) {
    alumnos.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (snap.child("dni_alum").getValue().equals(usuario) && snap.child("clave").getValue().equals(contra)) {
                    view.onSuccess(snap.getValue(Alumno.claass));
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    view.onError(databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });

    profesores.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (snap.child("dni_profe").getValue().equals(usuario) && snap.child("clave").getValue().equals(contra)) {
                    view.onSuccess(snap.getValue(Profesor.class));
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            view.onError(databaseError.getMessage());

        }
    });

    admins.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (snap.child("dni").getValue().equals(usuario) && snap.child("clave").getValue().equals(contra)) {
                    view.onSuccess(snap.getValue(Admin.class));
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            view.onError(databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

}

Así te lanzará directo a la app cuando encuentre al usuario, y por ultimo el MainActivity que quedaría algo así:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainInterface.View {
private EditText miEditTextLoginNombre, miEditTextLoginPass;
private Button miBotonLoginEntrar;


private String usuario, contra;
Snackbar sBar;
private MainInterface.Model model;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    model = new MainModel(this);
    miEditTextLoginNombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLoginNombre);
    miEditTextLoginPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLoginPass);
    miBotonLoginEntrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoginEntrar);



    miBotonLoginEntrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            usuario = miEditTextLoginNombre.getText().toString();
            contra = miEditTextLoginPass.getText().toString();

            if (usuario.isEmpty() || contra.isEmpty()) {
                sBar = Snackbar.make(view, "Hay campos vacíos", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                sBar.show();
            } else {
                model.handleCheck(usuario, contra);
            }
        }
    });
}


@Override
public <T> void onSuccess(T t) {
    if (t instanceof Admin){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Has iniciado sesión como Admin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (t instanceof Alumno){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Has iniciado sesión como User", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (t instanceof Profesor){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Has iniciado sesión como User", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    };
}

@Override
public void onError(String error) {
    Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}